# How can I get SweetFX to work with RadeonPro?

Tags: amd-radeon

I was trying out SweetFX for radeonpro so I could make a global profile and play it on all my games with standard settings that help improve them across the board and make profiles for what didn't work nicely with them.

I was unable to see any changes with newest sweetfx within my games even though sweetfx 1.4 worked with no issues. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four days ago I found the solution and posted in steam group for SweetFX.

Solution for: SweetFX 1.5 Fix for RadeonPro Compatibility

[Main.h](http://www.mediafire.com/view/ya364kzyk9z6aec/Main.h) replaces the file in your (SweetFX/Shaders) folder

[Code Changes](https://gist.github.com/Astralchaos/6518c74b837c13997f5e/revisions) The following minor change in code fixed it.

This has allowed me to use RadeonPro with sweetfx 1.5.

I heard this fix has been discovered before but personally I figured it out myself.

Steps I did:

1) Replaced each file in main folder until it has a effect (no effect at all)

2) Replaced the subfolder (sweetfx had a effect)

3) Replaced with each folder within sweetfx (only shaders had a effect)

4) Replaced vibrance (had no effect)

5) Replaced top half ( had no effect) then bottom half (had a effect)(

6) Spotted main.h (compared to main.h of sweetfx 1.4 and noticed a change in the script and deleted 
the sweetfx_ part)

7) Worked

Steam Group Original Post: http://steamcommunity.com/groups/SweetFX/discussions/0/616189106403430938/